# how to eliminate union for better performance in mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, query-performance

Hi i want fetch the records depends on different condition i used union worked fine but taking more than 15 secs so how can we eliminate union or make the query faster

QUERY:

```
(SELECT p.professional_id,
        p.company_name,
        pbt.name AS professional_business_type_name,
        pbtm.kukun_url,
        p.kukun_score,
        cc.year_founded,
        p.contractor_category,
        p.permit_data_count,
        p.cost_range_code,
        fpcr.cost_min_value,
        fpcr.cost_max_value
 FROM   professional p
        INNER JOIN company_contact cc
                ON cc.company_contact_id = p.company_contact_id
        INNER JOIN professional_business_type_map AS pbtm
                ON pbtm.professional_id = p.professional_id
        INNER JOIN of_professional_business_type_organization AS pbt
                ON pbt.professional_business_type_organization_id =
                   pbtm.professional_business_type_organization_id
        INNER JOIN f_professional_cost_range fpcr
                ON fpcr.cost_range_code = p.cost_range_code
 WHERE  p.professional_id != 262100
        AND cc.company_city_id = 5229
        AND pbt.professional_business_type_organization_id = 2
        AND p.cost_range_code = 4
 ORDER  BY p.kukun_score DESC
 LIMIT  5)
UNION
(SELECT p.professional_id,
        p.company_name,
        pbt.name AS professional_business_type_name,
        pbtm.kukun_url,
        p.kukun_score,
        cc.year_founded,
        p.contractor_category,
        p.permit_data_count,
        p.cost_range_code,
        fpcr.cost_min_value,
        fpcr.cost_max_value
 FROM   professional p
        INNER JOIN company_contact cc
                ON cc.company_contact_id = p.company_contact_id
        INNER JOIN professional_business_type_map AS pbtm
                ON pbtm.professional_id = p.professional_id
        INNER JOIN of_professional_business_type_organization AS pbt
                ON pbt.professional_business_type_organization_id =
                   pbtm.professional_business_type_organization_id
        INNER JOIN f_professional_cost_range fpcr
                ON fpcr.cost_range_code = p.cost_range_code
 WHERE  p.professional_id != 262100
        AND cc.company_city_id = 5229
        AND pbt.professional_business_type_organization_id = 2
 ORDER  BY p.kukun_score DESC
 LIMIT  5)
UNION
(SELECT p.professional_id,
        p.company_name,
        pbt.name AS professional_business_type_name,
        pbtm.kukun_url,
        p.kukun_score,
        cc.year_founded,
        p.contractor_category,
        p.permit_data_count,
        p.cost_range_code,
        fpcr.cost_min_value,
        fpcr.cost_max_value
 FROM   professional p
        INNER JOIN company_contact cc
                ON cc.company_contact_id = p.company_contact_id
        INNER JOIN professional_business_type_map AS pbtm
                ON pbtm.professional_id = p.professional_id
        INNER JOIN of_professional_business_type_organization AS pbt
                ON pbt.professional_business_type_organization_id =
                   pbtm.professional_business_type_organization_id
        INNER JOIN f_professional_cost_range fpcr
                ON fpcr.cost_range_code = p.cost_range_code
 WHERE  p.professional_id != 262100
        AND cc.company_city_id = 5229
 ORDER  BY p.kukun_score DESC
 LIMIT  5)
UNION
(SELECT p.professional_id,
        p.company_name,
        pbt.name AS professional_business_type_name,
        pbtm.kukun_url,
        p.kukun_score,
        cc.year_founded,
        p.contractor_category,
        p.permit_data_count,
        p.cost_range_code,
        fpcr.cost_min_value,
        fpcr.cost_max_value
 FROM   professional p
        INNER JOIN company_contact cc
                ON cc.company_contact_id = p.company_contact_id
        INNER JOIN professional_business_type_map AS pbtm
                ON pbtm.professional_id = p.professional_id
        INNER JOIN of_professional_business_type_organization AS pbt
                ON pbt.professional_business_type_organization_id =
                   pbtm.professional_business_type_organization_id
        INNER JOIN f_professional_cost_range fpcr
                ON fpcr.cost_range_code = p.cost_range_code
 WHERE  p.professional_id != 262100
        AND cc.company_state_id = 5
 ORDER  BY p.kukun_score DESC
 LIMIT  5)
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Is the union definitely the cause of the slow performance? How long does each query take when run individually?

Answer (score 0):

**(Likely Bug)**  You need `ORDER  BY p.kukun_score DESC` before the `UNION's` `LIMIT 5`.  *Today* MySQL may sequentially perform all parts of the `UNION`, combine all of them, *then* do the `LIMIT`.   In some future version, it is likely to, for example, perform the `SELECTs` in parallel, thereby jumbling the results.

Hence if you want the rows from the first `SELECT` to be delivered first, you must add a column and `ORDER BY`.

```
 ( SELECT 1 AS sequence, ... )
 UNION ALL
 ( SELECT 2 AS sequence, ... )
 ...
 ORDER BY sequence, kukun_score DESC
 LIMIT 5
```

Also, `UNION` is the same as `UNION DISTINCT`, which add a de-dup pass to the operation.  That is, the semantics *requires* evaluating all the selects.

**These `INDEXes` may help:**

```
cc:  (company_state_id, company_contact_id, year_founded)
cc:  (company_city_id, company_contact_id, year_founded)
fpcr:  (cost_range_code, cost_max_value, cost_min_value)
```

Those indexes will be "covering" and optimal for the SQL you have.

Some benefit will come from moving `fpcr` out of the union.  That is, first `UNION` all the other tables, *then* `JOIN` to `fpcr`. to get the two columns from it.  This will speed things up because it it needs to reach into that table only 5 times, instead of thousands times (however many rows are in the 4 temporary tables).

Comment: (Bug) You need ORDER  BY p.kukun_score DESC before the UNION's LIMIT 5. 
yes because the requirement is get only 5 records and the out put should come from first matching set 
for example:
in the first query we got 5 records then no need to go for second query
if in the first query we got 3 records then need to get the remaining two records from lower queries using union

please help me to get the output in any other ways....
thanks in advance

Comment: @naveenchennu - I elaborated in my Answer.